# Django Logging and Session Information

Tags: python, django, session, logging

I have tried to google this one to death but could not find the answer, so if someone can point me to the doc or explain how to do this that would be great.

I am trying to include Session information from the Django request (i.e cookies) in all logs, now this is fine in the views etc that have access to the request I can just format that in the message that I am logging.

The issue is with installed packages, these have no knowledge of the session and log without this information and I am yet to find a way to define this in the formatter so that the formatter is more session aware.

I need to do this as I have to send all logs to a syslog server and would like to be able to search the logs for an entire session and get even package level logs.

EDIT:

Sorry guys I am editing the question for a little more clarity.

The overall goal is to wrap all messages that get generated in a api call with the session information this would include any packages that are not directly tied to the Django application itself, this is so that I can search for all logs relating to a session. I hope this makes sense

Thanks

John.

Comment: Show us the code where your package related code statements is being logged!

Comment: The question is more generic than I can show with a code snippet, The question is more how can I use the formatter correctly to inject the session information into the all logs that are generated per session?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore

s = SessionStore()
# stored as seconds since epoch since datetimes are not serializable in JSON.
s['last_login'] = 1376587691
>>> s.create()
>>> s.session_key
'2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead'
```

Django docs ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I am still a little fuzzy on how I can use this in the Django logging formatter, also the packages would still not know about this variable, unless I pass this to them specifically, and to make these packages modular they should know nothing about the session directly.